# Python loop get last output

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, openpyxl

How do I get the last output from this loop?

```
for row in row2:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'a':
            result_str = cell.column
            print(result_str)
```

The output I keep getting is:

```
B
C
D
E
F
G
None
```

I thought making `result_str = list(cell.column)` but then I get many lists which I've unsuccessfully merged

```
['B']
['C']
['D']
['E']
['F']
['G']
None
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a single list that contains these values?  `[cell.column for row in row2 for cell in row if cell.value == 'a']`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, exactly. The post that James provided did answer my question.  Thank you!

Comment: If you spent seven hours getting nowhere on this then you should spent some more time learning the basics of Python.

Comment: Well said Charlie. In the process of it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you are trying to get a list of all of the `result_str` values.  In that case, you can create a list before any of your `for` loops, and append the result to that list.

```
result_list = []
for row in row2:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'a':
            result_list.append(cell.column)
print(result_list)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed with a [-1]. I'm new and still learning. Btw, I spent 7 hours today to no avail with this.